# Swift SLComposeServiceViewController loads forever even after every information is already there

Tags: ios, swift, webview, slcomposeviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

So,
I have a problem with `SLComposeServiceViewController`:
Even after the `presentationAnimationDidFinish` method was called and I already have all the information I need, the thing keeps downloading and I keep getting this kind of messages on the console:

```
[core] SLURLPreviewGenerator <SLURLPreviewGenerator: 0x170221ec0> webViewDidFinishLoad: still loading 1
```

After some time I also start getting memory issues as the memory is filling up with stupid metadata that it's downloading.

This only happens when using the CNN App atm, when trying to share Safari Links or from other apps, as soon as the view has finished loading everything is quiet on the console.

How can I access the `webViewDidFinishLoading` and set it to `still loading 0`?

**EDIT:** Usually it should give this `[core] SLURLPreviewGenerator <SLURLPreviewGenerator: 0x170030900> dealloc` ...

**EDIT 2:**
Here are 2 debug logs:
[image: log nr. 1: exit code 0]

[image: log nr. 2: already presented controller, still loading stuff]